# How to get sub-process info of installed apk on android device

Tags: android, subprocess, adb

We can define `android:process` for activity or service in `AndroidManifest.xml` named as sub-process.
for example, my package name is `'com.test.main'` and I defined two sub-processes:

```
android:process=":tool"
android:process=":bar"
```

My question is:

After install apk file into a android device, how can we get all these subprocess list info, for example `com.test.main:tool`, `com.test.main:bar`, through adb or another installed app?

Comment: non root android device

Answer (score 0):

```
    String pkg = "com.google.android.gms";
    try {

        // Ref: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads

        PackageInfo packageInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(pkg, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES | PackageManager.GET_SERVICES | PackageManager.GET_RECEIVERS | PackageManager.GET_PROVIDERS);


        List<ComponentInfo> list = new ArrayList<>();

        if (packageInfo.activities != null) Collections.addAll(list, packageInfo.activities);
        if (packageInfo.services != null) Collections.addAll(list, packageInfo.services);
        if (packageInfo.receivers != null) Collections.addAll(list, packageInfo.receivers);
        if (packageInfo.providers != null) Collections.addAll(list, packageInfo.providers);

        for (ComponentInfo componentInfo : list) {

            Utils.log("componentInfo: " + componentInfo.processName);
        }

    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

[image: Log output]